# How do you tell if an Expression<Func<T,object>> is referring to a root property, or is referring to a property of a property?

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I have:

`Expression<Func<Kitten, object>> someExpression = c => c.KittenName`

I use this to set the value of `KittenName`.

If the type is nested, I need to handle it differently, e.g.

`Expression<Func<Kitten, object>> someExpression = c => c.Address.StreetName`

How do I 'walk up the tree' so to speak from StreetName to Address, and/or detect that the expression is a nested one?

Comment: That's not a nested type - a nested type is where the type declaration itself is nested within another type. This is just a matter of one property expression building off another... which you can detect by looking at the target of the `MemberExpression`, which will be another `MemberExpression` instead of a `ParameterExpression`.

Comment: Can you explain how to do that? I get the expression.body as a MemberExpression but then I can't tell if it's the 'root' property so to speak or if it's a property of a property. If I try to set the property and it is not the 'root' property, it will set `c.StreetName` not `c.Address.StreetName`

Comment: As I say, you need to look at the target of the `MemberExpression` - so use `MemberExpression.Expression` and see whether that's another `MemberExpression`, or whether it's a `ParameterExpression`. But fundamentally, using this to *set* a value is a bad idea IMO. If you want an expression which *sets* a property, you should take an `Expression<Action<Kitten, Foo>>`. Otherwise you could easily find that the expression represents a read-only property.

Comment: Could you do something like `MemberExpression me = (MemberExpression)someExpression.Body; var isKitten = me.Expression.Type == typeof(Kitten);`?

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to work. I'd be interested to know why you have to check the `.Expression` of the `Expression` but perhaps I need to look at a tutorial of expression trees in more detail.